# DataTable stuck in "Processing" in R

Tags: r, shiny, mqtt, dt

I am trying to display the received MQTT data as a table in a `ShinyApp`, but the table is stuck in "Processing..". Below is my reproducible code. I tried with other solution but none of them seems to be working for my requirement.

```
library(shiny)
library(mqtt)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- shinyServer(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(plotOutput('plot'),
  fluidRow(dataTableOutput("telemetry"))
)
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  get_temps <- function(n) {

    i <- 0
    max_recs <- n
    readings <- vector("character", max_recs)

    temp_cb <- function(id, topic, payload, qos, retain) {
      i <<- i + 1
      readings[i] <<- readBin(payload, "character")
      return(if (i==max_recs) "quit" else "go")
    }

    mqtt::topic_subscribe(topic = "/outbox/crouton-demo/temperature",

                          message_callback = temp_cb)



    purrr::map(readings, jsonlite::fromJSON) %>%
      purrr::map(unlist) %>%
      purrr::map_df(as.list)

  }

  values <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)

  observeEvent(invalidateLater(450), {
    new_response <- get_temps(1)
    if (length(new_response) != 0) {

       values$x <- c(values$x, new_response$update.labels)
       values$y <- c(values$y, new_response$update.series)

    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    xdf <- data.frame(xval = values$x, yval = values$y)
    ggplot(xdf, aes(x = xval, y=yval)) + 
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      theme_ipsum_rc(grid="XY")
  })

  show_df <- reactive({

    xdf1 <- data.frame(xval = values$x, yval = values$y)

    return(xdf1)
  })

  output$telemetry <- renderDataTable({show_df()})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The `plot` seems to be working fine but cannot display the Data Table. tried with `library(DT)` but no luck.

Comment: How many rows does your `data.table` contain? Since everything is "translated to HTML and JavaScript there is are limitations (not caused by `data.table`) that can only be solved by paging the visible data...

Comment: Already read the FAQs, e. g. the section "server side processing"? https://datatables.net/faqs/index

Comment: @RYoda The number of rows cannot be specified. The rows keep on appending until the Application is open.

Comment: OK, without having the data and API it is difficult to reproduce the problem. Could you possibly identify the code row which is blocking (by step-wise commenting out/disabling suspicious code)?